# Data Tables adding more options?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi im trying to get jquery DataTables to work with more optins, I have this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').dataTable()
    .columnFilter({
    aoColumns: [ { type: "select", values: [ 'Gecko', 'Trident', 'KHTML', 'Misc', 'Presto', 'Webkit', 'Tasman']  },
                { type: "text" },
                 null,
                { type: "number" }
                    ],
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I want to add thease options but cant figure out where to place them:

```
"iDisplayLength": 50 ,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']]
}).columnFilter({....
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer <3